# Upload de archivo con PHP

Tags: php, formularios

No entiendo muy bien por que no me funciona un input tipo file en un formulario. Podéis ayudarme a encontrar el error?

**Formulario**:

```
<input type="file" name="imagen" class="form-control">
```

**Procesado**:

```
<?php
    $codigo = $_POST["codigo"];
    if (is_uploaded_file ($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'])) {
        $nombreDirectorio = "img/";
        $nombreFichero = $codigo;
        $nombreCompleto = $nombreDirectorio . $nombreFichero;
        move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'],
        $nombreCompleto);
        echo "Añadida con éxito";
    } else {
        echo "Error al subir imagen";
    }               
?>
```

Además he hecho a Apache propietario de los archivos y carpetas de la aplicación web para que tuviese todos los permisos.

Comment: Con esta información, difícil. Haz, como mínimo, un `var_dump` de  `$_FILES` a ver qué contiene.

Comment: puedes mostrar el codigo HTML del form? tienes agregado `enctype="multipart/form-data"` en este?

Comment: Muéstranos también el código <form> que envuelve al <input>, puede que sea cosa del enctype.

Comment: Era justo el enctype="multipart/form-data"  !! Que fallo más tonto :( Muchas gracias de verdad

Comment: @Cricket agregué la respuesta a tu pregunta para que puedas marcarla como correcta

Answer (score 5):

debes corroborar que tu `form` tenga el atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="file" />
</form>
```